# How do I use the DgsQueryExecutor with a dynamic GraphQL schema

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, graphql-java, netflix-dgs

I'm trying to test my graphQL schema using the `DgsQueryExecutor`. My GraphQL schema is dynamically created using `@DgsCodeRegistry` and `@DgsTypeDefinitionRegistry`.

This is the code for my test

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class DataFetcherRegistryTest {
    @Autowired
    private DgsQueryExecutor dgsQueryExecutor;


    @Test
    public void firstTest(){
        String value = dgsQueryExecutor.executeAndExtractJsonPath(
                "{ catalog { customer { test_attribute }}}",
                "data.catalog.customer.test_attribute");

        assertThat(value).isEqualTo("test-value");
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Field 'catalog' in type 'Query' is undefined
```

When the test loads it runs the method annotated with `@DgsCodeRegistry` but not the method annotated with `@DgsTypeDefinitionRegistry`. It only cares about the schema loaded from `schema.graphql` which in my case is empty because I'm creating the schema programmatically.

Comment: Could you please share your schema.graphqls, please?

Comment: my `schema.graphql` is empty. see edits.